# R: finding intersections in a subset by different column

Tags: r

I have a data set `age_structure` something like this:

```
MACHINE_NUMBER | MACHINE_KIND
         12345 | A
         12346 | A
         12347 | A
         12345 | B
         12348 | B
```

I need to somehow determine which MACHINE_NUMBER are in both MACHINE_KIND subsets. In this case, only 12345 should arise. So far I have tried subsetting the data frame like this, but because the MACHINE_KIND column is not in the subset, R throws an error:

```
common_numbers <- Reduce(intersect, list(subset(age_structure$MACHINE_NUMBER, MACHINE_KIND == "A"), subset(age_structure$MACHINE_NUMBER, MACHINE_KIND == "B")))

object 'MACHINE_KIND' not found
```

Defining the `age_structure` name as part of the condition runs the code without error, but the resulting `common_numbers` is empty.

```
common_numbers <- Reduce(intersect, list(subset(age_structure$MACHINE_NUMBER, age_structure$MACHINE_KIND == "A"), subset(age_structure$MACHINE_NUMBER, age_structure$MACHINE_KIND == "B")))
```

MACHINE_NUMBER and MACHINE_KIND are both factors. What is the advisable thing to do?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible input data?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of different `MACHINE_KIND` you find for each `MACHINE_NUMBER`

```r
library(data.table)
df[,n := uniqueN("MACHINE_KIND"), by = "MACHINE_NUMBER"][n>=2]
```

If you are only interested in `A` and `B` categories, filter first:

```r
library(data.table)
df["MACHINE_KIND" %in% c("A","B"),n := uniqueN("MACHINE_KIND"), by = "MACHINE_NUMBER"][n>=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R one-liner:

```
unique(Reduce(function(x, y){setdiff(x, y)}, split(df$MACHINE_NUMBER, df$MACHINE_NUMBER)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dplyr` package and the `stringr` package to check if the `MACHINE_NUMBER` has both (or more) kinds.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

a <- tibble::tribble(
    ~MACHINE_NUMBER, ~MACHINE_KIND,
    12345L,           "A",
    12346L,           "A",
    12347L,           "A",
    12345L,           "B",
    12348L,           "B"
) 

a %>% 
    group_by(MACHINE_NUMBER) %>% 
    summarize(both = if_else(all(str_detect(MACHINE_KIND, unique(a$MACHINE_KIND))), "yes", "no"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   MACHINE_NUMBER both 
#> *          <int> <chr>
#> 1          12345 yes  
#> 2          12346 no   
#> 3          12347 no   
#> 4          12348 no
```

Then you could filter them if you want, just in case you want to do more analyses with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
# example dataset
dt = read.table(text = "
MACHINE_NUMBER | MACHINE_KIND
12345 | A
12346 | A
12347 | A
12345 | B
12348 | B
", header=T, sep="|")
```

One option using base R

```
# create table based on unique rows of your dataframe
tbl = table(unique(dt)$MACHINE_NUMBER)

# get those that have 2 rows (i.e. belong in both groups)
names(tbl)[tbl == 2]

# [1] "12345"
```

Another option using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(MACHINE_NUMBER) %>%
  summarise(Counts = n_distinct(MACHINE_KIND)) %>%
  filter(Counts == 2)

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#      MACHINE_NUMBER Counts
#              <dbl>  <int>
#   1          12345      2
```

Note that if you have multiple groups you can use `>= 2`, instead of `== 2`.